# Trying to make a dll injector in c++, a few errors show up

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

DWORD GetProcId(const char* procName)
{
    DWORD procId = 0;
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry;
        procEntry.dwSize = sizeof(procEntry);

        if (Process32First(hSnap, &procEntry))
        {
            do
            {
                if (!_stricmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName))
                    {
                        procId = procEntry.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &procEntry));
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(hSnap);
    return procId;
}

int main()
{
    const char* dllPath = "C:\\Users\\%User%\\Desktop\\dll.dll";
    const char* procName = "csgo.exe";
    DWORD procId = 0;

    while (!procId)
    {
        procId = GetProcId(procName);
        Sleep(30);
    }

    HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, procId);

    if (hProc && hProc != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        void* loc = VirtualAllocEx(hProc, 0, MAX_PATH, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_READWRITE);

        WriteProcessMemory(hProc, loc, dllPath, strlen(dllPath) + 1, 0);

        HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProc, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA, 
loc, 0, 0);

        if (hThread)
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
    }

    if (hProc)
     {
        CloseHandle(hProc);
     }
    return 0;
}
```

The 2 errors that popped up:

First one:

> Error (active)    E0167   argument of type "WCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type 
>   "const char

Second one:

> Error C2664   'int _stricmp(const char *,const char *)': cannot convert argument 1 from 
>   'WCHAR [260]' to 'const char *'

Am I missing inclusions?

basically it won't run correctly, and those are the only 2 errors I get, I fixed the other ones. I just can't seem to figure this one out. I've tried removing some stuff, adding some stuff, but I dont know much about inclusions. If someone who does know inclusions sees a missing one, please let me know. I've tried a lot of stuff on this.

Answer (score 0):

You should include wchar.h
and use wchar_t instead of char.
char normally is 1 byte, while wchar would be 2 bytes.

You can find out more details here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/char-wchar-t-char16-t-char32-t?view=vs-2019

Also, you should use: _wcsicmp instead of _stricmp
See more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stricmp-wcsicmp-mbsicmp-stricmp-l-wcsicmp-l-mbsicmp-l?view=vs-2019

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? Im still confused on what you mean. Could you send back an example maybe? I included wchar, what now?

Comment: "const char* dllPath"     =>     "const wchar_t* dllPath". Same for "procName" in main and GetProcId. ("const char* procName" => "const wchar_t* procName").  And replace _stricmp with _wcsicmp '_stricmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName)' => '_wcsicmp(procEntry.szExeFile, procName)'.